# NoClassDefFoundError in Android JUnit Test Project after moving class to new package in Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, noclassdeffounderror

I recently updated my original **Android project** and moved some files into new packages for better organisation.

Prior to updating my project packages, I had created an **Android JUnit Test Project** which I had linked to some intern packages representing my applications Model. All of my Test Cases were passing.

Upon moving some of my classes into new sub-Packages, my tests are now failing with a `NoClassDefFoundError`, which is appear because the simple relocation of my classes into new packages.

[image]

I reworked my TestCase classes to update the modified include statements, removing all reference errors that emerge upon re-packaging.

I then deleted the tests *Run Configurations* in hope that when I re-ran the tests this would resolve any build paths errors, but it has not resolved the issue.

I am fairly new to JUnit Testing and I'm sure that there is some simple fix, but I can't figure it out.

I've looked at some other questions, but the ones that seem semi-related are using libs and jars, not simple internal package changes.

My packages changed from:

```
app.model
```

To

```
app.model.app
```

NOTE: When I run the Android Project, the app works fine (the repackaging hasn't effect the application). It is as though the test project is pointing to the old .apk and not the new .apk

An explanation of how to resolve this issue would be appreciated. I am interested in growing my understanding of Android JUnit Testing.

Thanks!

Comment: Try closing your emulator and restart it with the AVD Manager. Be sure to click on "Clear User Data".

Comment: I was running on an actual device, I'm sure your solution would have worked but it turns out that I had an typo in my Android JUnit Manifest file after refactor -> renaming a parent package. Run Configurations where updated with the refactor, but not the separate Manifest file. Thanks for your help, I do appreciate it.